# How to make Windows Powershell (5.1) the default integrated terminal in a VSCode project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a small project that depends on *Windows PowerShell* (5.1).

```
MyReport/
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── Classes.ps1
├── Get-Report.ps1
└── config.jsonc
```

When I open the folder MyReport, it always starts PowerShell 7 in the integrated terminal.

My `.vscode/settings.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Windows PowerShell",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
}
```

What do I have to change, to make Windows PowerShell (5.1) the integrated terminal?

I'm using VSCode version 1.66.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

On the terminal ribbon you can find an arrow (next to the + sign).
Select `configure terminal setting`.
Look for:

```
Terminal › External: Windows Exec
Customizes which terminal to run on Windows.
```

Type:
`C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe`

Disclaimer: `not tested`

Answer (score 2):

1. Within vs-code, in the terminal window, click the dropdown icon right next to the "+" (plus) icon.
2. Find the option "Select Default Profile", another dropdown should appear from the top of the application window.
3. Find the powershell correct reference, i use 'pwsh.exe' located in my powershell version 7 folder

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way in there using UI. IT is the way-

1. [image]
2. [image]

By clicking the red marked areas, you are done. Congratulations for setting PowerShell as your default terminal!!